# Where are ALL locations of Start Menu folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am trying to fix start menu damage after windows 10 install.

Currently, I removed all files from known locations of start menu files, but still have some entries in Start Menu.

Here is the proof folders are empty:

[image]

And here is the proof that I still have some entries in Main Menu:

[image]

What are all locations of Start Menu folders in Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried googling? Location of this folder hasn't changed since Vista, it's `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.

Comment: I does not coincide too. I can post proof, but trust me it is.

Comment: @gronostaj I posted a proof, please remove downvote.

Comment: @fixer1234 The path content does not coincide with Start Menu content. For example, path contains two `YourKit Java Profiler*` entries, `Бесплатные игры Atarata`, `Декларация 2012`, `Игры Alawar` and `Игры от Alawar` entries, which are not in menu.

Comment: @fixer1234 reversely, Start Menu contains `Xming` and `XnView` entries, which are not in the folder.

Comment: @fixer1234 there are numerous differences; in fact I can't use `Start Menu` after upgrade to `Windows 10` at all. To run program, I open folder in Explorer and search for `*.lnk` files. I can do this of course, but would like to fix it.

Comment: Try C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Comment: @Moab It contains one more mixture, but no full conicidence. Can post proof if you don't believe.

Comment: Not all start menu entries are in that folder.  I believe anything in the equivalent "all users" folder gets included, plus there are other routes to the menu.  That directory is mainly for you to be able to add things.  As to why some directory items aren't in the menu, are they executables or links to executables?

Comment: Isn't it possible to know explicitly, which folder Windows uses to show Start Menu? I

Comment: @fixer1234 they are folders with `lnk` files, and these `lnk` files work fine if double click them with mouse from File Explorer.

Comment: Probably folders are excluded if duplicated in multiple places?

Comment: re: your previous comment, I don't believe everything in the start menu is located in a single folder.

Comment: @fixer1234 I know it collects from several folders. But why isn't it include all it finds?

Comment: That one I can't answer.

Comment: I believe you, I upvoted, windows 10 just sucks...

Comment: Your question originated because you couldn't find a folder with a 1:1 match to the start menu contents.  Part of that answer is that there are multiple sources for the menu, so no single folder is guaranteed to contain everything.  The other part is why subdirectories in the main user-specific folder are not showing up in the menu when they contain working links.  That's the only portion of the question that lacks an answer.  You might have a better shot if you refocus the question specifically on that.

Comment: "For example, path contains two YourKit Java Profiler* entries..." -- The bottom screenshot shows those folders in the path.  Several other folders, XBMC and ZDT, are also in the path and show up in the displayed portion of the Start Menu as pull-down entries (which is how folders are displayed).  Just to confirm, those two YourKit folders aren't displayed on any page in the Start Menu?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, they are absent; numerous entries are absent; in fact, my entire Start Menu is useless now; to run any program, I am opening Far Manager, opening Start Menu folder in it and doing search for appropriate *.lnk file. I.e. I am doing by hand what Windows should do with it's Start Menu feature.

Comment: @fixer1234 if you don't believe me, please note, that entries are sorted alphabetically; since `Y` goes between `X` and `Z`, `YourKit*` should be shown between `XMBC` and `ZDT`.

Comment: X,Z,3,H,C is alphabetical?  I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that your locale and language setting isn't US English (had help from a few other clues, too, on that one).  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 These letters are Russian, they are really alphabetical, locale is irrelevant. Check my revised question please: I have removed ALL files from menu folders, but I still have some items in menu.

Comment: Interesting.  Some are folders, and some of the programs have no icon.  It's also interesting that some folders show up in the menu and some don't.  You could do a search to find where the displayed stuff is located to identify the folders.  I'm wondering if Win 10 is using a different mechanism, like using installed programs from the registry rather than relying on folder searches, plus including items you place in one of the dedicated start menu folders.  Moab might have the right idea (maybe Win 10 isn't ready for prime time).

Comment: I have done the search but found nothing. I sought drive C: Menu files are now on D: where I kept them for time, but I expect menu can't populate from there. I was copying with Far file manager hence unprobable that windows tracked the path. So, I am coming to conclusion, that @qasdfdsaq is right: data is stored somewhere in "proprietary database"

Answer (score 164):

You can find it here :

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

which, in a standard installation, refer to

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

To me that includes all folders and files in the start screen.

But maybe you installed programs, then uninstalled them- but the folders remained there hence the extra folders or files.

In my case all that was in that folder existed in the Start menu.

Comment: This isn't everything, what about cortana, voice recorder, alarms and clock, etc? I don't know where those things are coming from because it's neither of those locations.

Comment: @HonsaStunna, Windows Apps do not function the same way as traditionally installed programs. You may want to reference the following article on removing .appx files if this achieves your goal. (Windows Apps) from your system: [Remove APPX Package For All Users](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users). See also: [Remove Provisioned Apps During Windows Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/remove-provisioned-apps-during-update) as Apps may reappear after feature updates or other user logins.

Comment: I was looking out for the location of pin to start menu items and this helped me:
`%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: FYI, there is no AppData folder for the Public user.

Comment: Shortcuts in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder also appear in the Start menu, not just those in the Programs subfolder.

Comment: Neither of these folders contains Store-installed app shortcuts.

Comment: In the Windows Explorer (WIN + E), type `shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-B780-3893943456e1}` into the text box to open the start menu's folder. Then, right click on any icon and select "Open file location" to get to the related shortcut. I got this tip from [here.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-does-windows-10-keep-the-start-menu/d735b97c-61d0-4268-b38c-28d5562ccdb5)

Answer (score 23):

Since you're familiar with PowerShell, there are several possible solutions ...

And yes, I'm in Win 10:

```
PS > [Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      10586  0
```

## Ask Windows (.NET)

Ask Windows (.NET to be specific) where the location is. This will resolve the correct location in case you, like me, moved your `AppData\Roaming` folder into a *[DropBox](https://db.tt/QghuGCXU)-like* location.

```
PS > [Environment]::GetFolderPath('StartMenu')
C:\Users\VertigoRay\DropBox\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
PS > [Environment]::GetFolderPath('CommonStartMenu')
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

[More about GetFolderPath.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

## Delete Corrupted AppLocker Files

PowerShell (As Admin):

```
PS > Get-ChildItem "${env:SystemRoot}\System32\AppLocker\Plugin*.*" | %{ Move-Item $_ "${_}.bak" }
```

*Restart Windows after you run the command.*

## DISM Restore Health

PowerShell (As Admin):

```
& dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

*Restart Windows after you run the command.*

## Re-register App Packages

PowerShell (As Admin):

```
PS > Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | %{ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" }
```

*You might get some errors (red text). Typically this is saying the `.xml` can't be found; just ignore it.*

## Re-index

[As previously linked in this thread](https://superuser.com/a/960489/205119), simply re-indexing your drive should cause the Start Menu DB to refresh. I would turn off indexing, then turn it all back on.

Turning off indexing deleted the indexing files in previous versions of Windows; I haven't tested this in Windows 10. If needed, you can manually delete the indexing files once indexing is turned off; might need to reboot after turning indexing off to release all open handles. The default location for the indexing files is: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search`

Comment: This is a really great answer. Thanks for information about `GetFolderPath`.

Answer (score 14):

Although completely non-obvious, it is actually very simple.

Windows-R to open the `run menu` and type:

`shell:programs`. This opens the equivalent of `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

`shell:common programs`. This opens the equivalent of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

I personally use `shell:startup` a lot to open the folder where shortcuts are located for starting up automatically.

You can find the full list on the [winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/) site.

Answer (score 10):

### The folder you are looking for does not exist.

Windows 10's start menu uses a Microsoft proprietary database, **there is no folder.**

When you click "All Programs" in the start menu, Windows shows all programs listed in it's start menu database. The database is populated with items from multiple locations as fixer1234 described, but ultimately it is the contents of the database that are shown and not any specific folder(s).

Comment: How to manipulate this database? How to remove/add items from/to it?I have my Start Menu completely damaged and need to fix it.

Comment: PS Looks like you are The One who knows truth :)

Comment: @Dims: I don't know, but try http://superuser.com/questions/954843/force-a-rebuild-of-the-start-menu-program-index-database-in-windows-10 or https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=start+menu+windows+10+database

Comment: This answer just shifts the question from "where is the folder" to "where is the database".

Comment: This is just an aggressive way of saying 'the information comes from multiple folders'

Comment: It turns out that the folder DOES exist. See my answer below. It's just that it's a system folder that doesn't follow the typical file-folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the (some say silly) proprietary binary Win10 StartMenu database is located at:

- **Orthodox:** %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\

But that's not the whole story (AFAICT).

There is a right (orthodox) side to the Windows 10 start menu (groups & tiles), and a left side (alphabetical words) ... where that left side comprises at least two components (user and global).

So that makes for three locations, if you consider both the alphabetical and orthodox portions of the Windows 10 Start Menu.

Left side (alphabetical app names):

- **Global:** %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
- **User:** %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

The orthodox (right side tiles) of the Win10 startmenu is the binary hive at:

- **Orthodox:** %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\vedatamodel.edb

Note that this orthodox tile-menu hive is of fixed 1024KB size (which likely explains the reputed limit of 500 entries) and fixed date (which likely indicates the purported secret things going on inside of Win10 that I can't myself explain but maybe others can explain).

As proof of concept, (as admin or another user) you can COPY the entire binary orthodox "Database" hive, and then change your Windows 10 orthodox menus, and then copy back your archived orthodox hive, and you'd get your old menus back.

Comment: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer` - This folder no longer exists (checked on Windows 10 18363 / version 1909)

Answer (score 3):

To add additional information to qasdfdsaq's and DodiNj's answer

The UWP Apps location are in the following route in a system folder:

When using Run from Windows Key + R

```
explorer.exe shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-B780-3893943456e1}
```

When typing into the address bar in File Explorer you don't need the exe file in the command.

```
explorer.exe shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-B780-3893943456e1}
```

[Here's the source.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-does-windows-10-keep-the-start-menu/d735b97c-61d0-4268-b38c-28d5562ccdb5)

Answer (score 1):

I hate to burst any bubbles, but **there is no database**.
There are 3 places to look -- but i am still looking for 1 more:
Of course to find these you need to File Explorer view to show hidden and system files. If you can't do that you shouldn't be messing here.

This contains items pinned to the start menu - not the all programs list
??????????????????????????????????? **Who can answer this** ???????????

This contains items loaded for specific users
*C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu*

This contains items loaded for all users
*C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu*

This contains items pinned to the taskbar per user
*C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar*

In Windows 10, I have not found a use for items in
*C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch* . I guess you could add it as a new toolbar as done in Windows 7 and earlier but I see no point.

Comment: This should really be posted as a comment, or as a new question (or both). It is not an actual answer.

Comment: Also, yes, it is a Database in Windows 10. You can think of it as a cache, but it's a database acting like a cache in that case. Or vice versa. The database caches the entries from several folders you mention, and sometimes does not update itself when those locations are changed/updated. As such, sometimes the fix is to remove an entity from one or more folders, and sometimes you have to refresh the DB itself.

Answer (score 1):

as per DodiNj answer, these are the "source folders" for the Start Menu:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

But... I would also suggest to check if the same program is referenced by two shortcuts: in that case ONLY ONE ICON is displayed in the Start Menu, so you cannot see it in another folder. It seems you cannot have the same application twice in the Start Menu, even if you use links with different name or placed in different sub-folders. I had a similar issue, just leave one shortcut for one program.

Comment: by the way, this can be an implicit confirmation about the db that uses different sources but eventually it allows (or returns) one record per app.

Answer (score 0):

The single proprietary multi-file binary Win10 StartMenu database is located at:
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\

Comment: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer` - This folder no longer exists (checked on Windows 10 18363 / version 1909)

Answer (score 0):

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository>

StateRepository-Deployment.srd
StateRepository-Machine.srd

These files are database files and need to be open with SQLiteDatabase.  I know when I have a corrupt start menu based upon broken "windows store apps" I have to edit these files.

Answer (score 0):

There is, thus far, one location not yet mentioned - That is for `Windows Store Apps` and other `'semi-system' applications` (not quite sure what to call them), like WSL installations.

These application links can be found at:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

There seems to a fair amount of voodoo magic going on there.  For instance, the 'application links' are files ending with `.exe` extension but are 0 byte length files, Where the base files are located, I'm still not sure yet.  Nor do I know how the actual 'linking' takes place.

If you find additional information on these applications, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Things being stored in some database is the silliest thing I've read. That's just not true. If you want to play around with your files and folders on the start menu, just go to this directory and you can adjust them as you like:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: I agree with the "silliest thing" part. Unfortunately it IS true. Even more silly is that in Windows 10 10240 this database was limited to about 500 entries; if you had more in your Start Menu folders (from which the database was populated) the 'extras' were just ignored. See http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/07/review-windows-10-is-the-best-version-yet-once-the-bugs-get-fixed/ , section title "A new Start menu, not necessarily a better one". Me, I just installed Start10 and said goodbye to the still-broken Windows Start Menu. I'll have to try Classic Shell sometime too.

Comment: It might, be silly, but you can't say it's not true. Open that folder and then open your start menu... now, try to find "Calendar", "Camera" and other bloatware in that folder, it's not there, is it?

Answer (score -1):

I searched the hard drive for the file (In my case it was bytefence.exe) Found and deleted it.

I reopened start menu programs and then tried to load the program.

Windows showed an error message asking me if I wanted to delete the shortcut because the file no longer existed, I answered Yes and the Start Menu removed the link automatically.

Hope it helps you old fogies like me who were looking for a directory to remove. lol

Answer (score -1):

If you right click on some of the icons then you get an option to open file location.
So I was looking for a way to add some useful shortcuts to the right of the menu.
So I right clicked on "Computer Info" under the "System Tools" heading and opened its location (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`).
I then added a new shortcut in that folder (for mstsc.exe) and it then appeared under the "System Tools" heading.
You can then drag the shortcut to your preferred Heading if you want.