# Remove appx package for all users

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store, appx

Fresh Windows 10 install. Somehow the MSN Weather app became corrupted. (Unable to launch) I removed the app with the following Powershell command:

> Remove-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.BingWeather_4.7.118.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe

However, when running

> Get-Appxpackage –Allusers

the package is still present. When I attempt to reinstall the app via the Windows Store, the download is skipped and the same corrupted package is installed.

I've tried restarting (many times) and using `WSReset` to no avail.

What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: you have to use Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage to remove buildin apps: Remove-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName <PackageName>

Comment: I'm getting "the system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: DId you try running the command as Administrator from the powershell console?

Answer (score 16):

Tested on Windows 10 1709-22H2 and 11 21H2-22H2  :

```
Get-AppxPackage -all *NAME_OF_THE_APPX* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

-all: This parameter is used to retrieve information about all Appx packages installed on the computer.

-AllUsers: This parameter is used to remove the Appx package for all users on the computer.

Comment: Theoretically it worked (I saw something happened, and `Get-AppxPackage -all *CandyCrush*` now shows empty), but unfortunately I still see gigabytes of CandyCrush & similar crap in the WindowsApps folder :( not a complaint to you, just to Microsoft I suppose :/

Comment: it ran, but I expected it to give back the disk space too.  I still see the app in WindowsApps  folder too

Answer (score 6):

The `Remove-AppxPackage` only removes store applications for the logged in user, even if you pipe it from **`Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers`**

I've had trouble updating apps in the past because another user had logged in and the app had been updated in their profile, it's also [a known issue when using sysprep.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/sysprep-fails-remove-or-update-store-apps)

You can identify if that is the case using this script:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Format-List -Property PackageFullName,PackageUserInformation.
```

In the output of this last cmdlet, check the users for whom the package is showing up as Installed. Delete these user accounts from the reference computer, or log on to the computer by using these user accounts & remove the Appx package, as you have been:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.BingWeather_4.7.118.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

If that still doesn't work, you could try removing the provisioning and installing it again from the Store.

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName Microsoft.BingWeather_4.7.118.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Comment: Careful to users removing store from provisioning, it can be a real hassle after reinstall; see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1449292/900431) to get store back, if you make this mistake!

Comment: "Remove-AppxPackage -allusers" works to remove app for users that are not logged in.
The -allusers is new.

Answer (score 5):

This will work in windows 10 1809:

```
get-appxpackage *pattern* | remove-appxpackage -AllUsers
```

or

```
remove-appxpackage -AllUsers -Package somepackagefullname
```

This is currently not working:

```
remove-appxpackage -User somesid -Package somepackagefullname
```

Piping anything to remove-appxpackage with no options will only remove the packages of the current user.  EDIT:  actually I think this will take care of current users but not new users.

Answer (score 4):

As of v1709 (Fall Creator's Update), there is a new "-AllUsers" flag for Remove-AppxPackage.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, but in the context of trying to sysprep a System which was already running for a few months.

I am running Windows 10 20H2 (19042.1052)

I think my problem was that the user which it was installed for did not exist anymore (I've deleted all users before) and Get-AppxPackage showed a very weired username: S-1-5-21-350941.... (followed by at least 32 "random" numbers)

I got it working with following command pipe:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where PackageFullName -eq {PackageFullName} | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

In my case {PackageFullName} was "Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackde-DE_19041.20.66.0.neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Hope that helps somebody ^^

Comment: How does this answer differ from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users/1202962#1202962) answer from 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1760403/how-to-uninstal-uwp-apps?noredirect=1#comment2736566_1760403) has been closed.  This is how to disable Cortana and App Store functionality.

There are a number of registry tweakers around.  [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10) from Windows Club is most suitable for this.  **I am not associated with any of the tweakers in anyway**

You can use the search feature to find all the tweaks for a topic.  Here are screenshots for Cortana and App Store.

[image: App Store]

[image: Cortana]

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers  *WindowsAlarms* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -allusers  *windowscommunicationsapps* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -allusers  *officehub* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

win 10 pro 1909

Comment: This solution has already been suggested by another user in 2017 and 2019 and one deleted answer in 2019.

Answer (score -2):

Best bet is to remove the apps from the image.
Weather is a provisioned app, meaning it will install a fresh copy for each user if present. This holds true for new version releases as well.
Check out Michael's article on removing them via task sequence, it's a great reference you can adapt for your particular methods.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/11/11/removing-windows-10-in-box-apps-during-a-task-sequence/

TL;DR - You have to remove it from the image if you want it to stay gone, else it will eventually reinstall for someone.

Comment: would you care to include the instructions from the link into your answer?

Comment: Basically, you'd use powershell and run 

get-startapps | format-list | out-file C:\users\username\desktop\startapps.txt

to isolate the target packages , and run the supplied script in the link after modifying the $AppsList variable definition.
Of course, replace username in the get-startapps cmdlet with your username.
You'll want to use format-list in the cmdlet to prevent truncation of package names.

I strongly advise picking through a few articles before doing this. There are provisioned and non-provisioned applications. Not enough room to type it all out.

Comment: Removing a non-provisioned package in the image can cause serious functionality loss. For example, removing Cortana components can cause SearchUI to break, since it is nested in Cortana's package for efficiency.

Answer (score -3):

After I remove the Windows Appx package with the above Remove-AppxPackage commands - I run the FREE version of CCleaner to uninstall any remaining apps.

Some Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 default apps have no uninstall option whatsoever. Maps for example, is built in. This is where CCleaner can help.

CCleaner makes managing apps easy by listing them all in one place and allowing you to uninstall them - even if they're built-in. To do this, open CCleaner and click on ‘Tools’. Simply select the unwanted app from the list and click ‘Uninstall’.

Comment: This answer reads like an advertisement for CCleaner.

Comment: I have tried CCleaner, it did not help me in removing Store apps leftovers at all. It did not see them, I did not find any options so that I can remove them.