# How do I stop the Windows 10 Photos app (and Runtime Broker) from pegging my cpu?

Tags: windows-10, photos

Every so often I'll notice my laptop fans kick into high gear for apparently no reason and my keyboard starts responding slowly.

Then I fire up Task Manager and see this...
Photos and Runtime Broker

[image: Photo Runtime Broker]

I've turned all the settings off within the Photos app.

[image: Photos app settings]

But it still insists on doing something behind the scenes.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Does it run in background? Take some time and see if the CPU usage automatically drops.

Comment: Yes.  It does run in the background and it automatically drops.  I want to stop it from ever starting.

Answer (score 10):

One way that might or might not work is to **deactivate it from running in the background**. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then go to `Privacy`, then to `Background Apps`. Switch off `Photos`.

---

Or, if you want to be a bit more drastic, you could simply **remove** the photo-app - this works and does not harm the system (though of course, you would need another viewer/organiser for your pictures).

Just fire up a PowerShell-Terminal as Administrator and type:

```cs
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers "*Photos*" | Remove-AppxPackage -Verbose
```

<sub>Derived from my very own [remove_win10_apps.ps1](https://github.com/flolilo/flolilos-PoShScripts/blob/master/system_tools/remove_win10_apps.ps1).</sub>

Further reading: [Remove appx package for all users](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users)

Comment: Thanks flolilolilo. That will work I'm sure.
Today I decided to remove all the linked folders (even those with no photos like the local Pictures folder) to see how that works.  I'll keep an eye on it.  Hopefully it's a less nuclear solution.

I love your full *remove_win10_apps.ps1.* script by the way.  Nice work!

Comment: @GollyJer Thanks - it really was just a matter of stitching together the information from various places in the fastest way possible. ;-)

Comment: You have to deactivate Photos from running in the background individually for all users on a PC. My wife's Photos process was still hammering the CPU even though I disabled it for me. Hopefully it's finally resolved.