# How to permanently remove unwanted apps from Windows 10 PRO?

Tags: windows-10

I have created a script that removes the unwanted applications from Windows after installing it on a new computer.

```
Get-AppxPackage *3dbuilder* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsalarms* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowscommunicationsapps* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowscamera* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *officehub* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *skypeapp* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *getstarted* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *zunemusic* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsmaps* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingfinance* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *zunevideo* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingnews* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *onenote* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *people* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsphone* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *photos* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingsports* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *soundrecorder* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingweather* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *xboxapp* | Remove-AppxPackage

cleanmgr /SAGERUN:1221
```

I am wondering about one thing: can I make this permanent? I was surprised when a new update brought back half of the apps. Is there a way to get updates only for the operating system and not for these crapwares?

Just for the record, this is not about how to uninstall certain features. This is about how to remove them PERMANENTLY.

Comment: You can't really, not without taking draconian and unrecommended steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove appx package for all users](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users)

Comment: I am going to flag this as a duplicate but wanted to add, the reason these applications are being reinstalled is that you are installing the feature updates from an unmodified image.  *In order to install a feature update, and have it NOT install those default applications, you have to modify the feature update image to NOT include these applications.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to uninstall Universal Apps through PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell)

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running and upgrading to?  Apps you uninstall are not added back and this has been the case for the last 4 releases and I can confirm this works fine.  See the 1703 release notes here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1703

Comment: Update system will not not bring them back, but upgrade after （might be ）Windows 10 1703 will bring them back to system. So permenently remove them is not accessable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You don't have to do anything any more.**

Since 1703 release Windows feature updates have not reinstalled apps you have chosen to remove.  I remove apps in the same manner using powershell and can confirm they are not readded and this has worked since 1703 up to and including the current 1809 release.

> **Uninstalled in-box apps no longer automatically reinstall**
>
> Starting with Windows 10, version 1703, in-box apps that were uninstalled by the user won't automatically reinstall as part of the feature update installation process.
>
> Additionally, apps de-provisioned by admins on Windows 10, version 1703 machines will stay de-provisioned after future feature update installations. This will not apply to the update from Windows 10, version 1607 (or earlier) to version 1703.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1703

Comment: Note: "This will not apply to the update from Windows 10, version 1607 (or earlier) to version 1703".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After (again) removing the apps with *PowerShell*, you can try [disabling "consumer features"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-installing-unwanted-apps/b0209eb9-3594-43ed-9b09-3ec115dd613d?auth=1) to prevent reinstallation:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\` (or copy/paste that into the *Regedit* location bar)
- Create a subkey under `Windows`: Right-click the Windows key and choose `New > Key`; name it `CloudContent`.
- Create a value: Right-click `CloudContent` and select `New > DWORD (32-bit) Value`; name it `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures`.
- Double-click the new value to set it to `1` and click `OK`.

[image: Disable Consumer "Features"]

You might also want to create a new value, `DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures`, and set it to `1` [to minimize network traffic between your PC and Microsoft's servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/manage-connections-from-windows-operating-system-components-to-microsoft-services).

**N.B.** Take this answer with a grain of salt: [Microsoft has ignored update settings](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/08/report-forced-windows-10-version-1709-upgrades-that-bypass-windows-update/?utm_source=fark&utm_medium=website&utm_content=link&ICID=ref_fark) in the past.

Comment: `DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures` to my knowledge only disables Spotlight.  Which would NOT disable nor uninstall any of those applications the author removed.  They also would be reinstalled, if the feature update was installed through Windows Update, or through the use of a mounted ISO of a feature update (i.e. 1809).  Any event this particular group policy (and thus the key associated with it) is only applicable to Enterprise and Education.

Comment: @Ramhound, correct: " DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures, and set it to 1 to minimize network traffic between your PC and Microsoft's servers." That's just a convenience to limit traffic, having nothing to do with apps -- but it's in the same Reg key. As far as preventing updates reinstalling undesired apps, I was not too hopeful in the first place, but it's worth a try. Only sure cure: move to Linux.

Comment: But the author wants to uninstall UWP, so how does this key, help the author achieve that if it's ignored since they are using [Windows 10 Professional](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-experience#experience-allowwindowsconsumerfeatures)?