# How do I completely delete all files of pre-installed apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

How do I completely delete all the files for pre-installed applications (e.g. CandyCrush) in Windows 10?

e.g. I want to remove the directory for CandyCrush
`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\king.com.CandyCrushSaga_1.1380.6.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32`
but Windows won't let me.

It says SYSTEM isn't giving me permission.

I have tried running a Windows PowerShell as Administrator and I tried running the command:

```
Remove-AppxPackage king.com.CandyCrushSaga_1.540.1.0_x86__khqwnzmzfus32
```

But I get "Deployment failed"

Background:
I want to get rid of all the stupid .JPG files associated with CandytCrush. I deeply resent the high-handed approach of Microsoft giving us all this bloatware that none of us asked for and also making it so hard to get rid of. It is wasting the space on my hard disk. And I don't want to see those .JPGs cluttering up my search results when I use Everything Search.

EDIT01:
CandyCrush does not appear to be installed. But I want to delete the installation files(!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove appx package for all users](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users) and [Unable to uninstall Universal Apps through PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell) and [How do I remove Candy Crush Saga from Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/958562/how-do-i-remove-candy-crush-saga-from-windows-10)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the file association with Candy Crush isn't supposed to be the case.  It sounds like your file association should be reset.

Comment: As per EDIT01. this question is different to the 'similar question' "Remove appx package for all users". Removing remnant installation files is a different method.

Answer (score 0):

In the article
[Windows 10 keeps installing Candy Crush games](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-keeps-installing-candy-crush-saga/),
the author has collected all known remedies, which I'll summarize below.

It should be noted that the situation on every computer is different.
On some Windows 10 computers Candy Crush is never installed, while
on others it is impossible to get rid off. The solutions below might or
might not help, singly or several together. Even if they help, this might
only be temporary.

1. [Perform a clean boot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/41804-perform-clean-boot-windows-10-troubleshoot-software-conflicts.html)
   and uninstall Candy Crush.
2. In an elevated Use PowerShell session enter the commands:

   ```
   Get-AppxPackage -User {your-user-name}   (use below the Candy Crush name)
   Remove-AppxPackage king.com.CandyCrushSaga_1.{found above}
   ```
3. In regedit, navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsStore\WindowsUpdate\AutoDownload`,
   find `AutoDownload` or create as a new 32-bit DWORD value, and set it to `2`.
4. Block Windows Update. (Somewhat desperate.)
5. Uninstall the Windows App Updater app, in *Settings > Apps*, locate
   Locate *App Updater* or *App Installer* and click Uninstall to remove it.
6. In *Settings > Personalization > Start*, disable
   *Occasionally show suggestions in Start*.
7. Sometimes ensuring Windows is totally patched solves the problem, in
   *Settings > Update & Security*, click *Check for updates*.
8. Turn off Microsoft Consumer Experience, in Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`),
   navigate to *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content*, double-click *Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences*, set
   to *Enabled* and click OK.
   This can also be done via regedit, key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent`,
   double-click `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures` (DWORD) set its Value to `1`.
9. Change the security policy, by running `secpol.msc`, go to
   *Application Control Policies > AppLocker*, choose *Packaged app Rules*,
   right-click empty space on the right pane and choose *Create New Rule*,
   select *Permissions* choose *Deny*, click *Next*, choose
   *Use an installed packaged app as a reference*, click *Select*,
   select *Widows Spotlight* from the list, click OK,
   move to *Package name* and click *Create*.