# How to uninstall UWP apps?

Tags: windows-10

When I go into Settings and then Apps, I can see a list of apps, some of which I would like to uninstall. For example Cortana or Microsoft Store, but the uninstall button is deactivated for these. Is there any way to get rid of these annoying apps without destroying the OS?

Comment: Cortana has been integrated with some of the Windows searches. Removing it made removed task bar search for me, when I tried it last.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Are you tallking about that search field near the Windos button?

Comment: Yes.  However, this is sorted now if you use a tweaker. Since this question has been closed, I have provided a GUI solution in that [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users/1760414#1760414)

Comment: @Rohit Gupta If this question wasn´t closed, would acept your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately,  it is almost impossible to get a closed question reopened. The main thing is you have a solution.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta At least I have upvoted the answer as helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, they do zero harm so uninstalling is not really necessary.

Second, if you must uninstall them, use Power Shell to do that.

Uninstall Cortana. please see:

[Uninstall Cortana](https://www.prajwal.org/how-to-uninstall-cortana-using-powershell/)

The steps to uninstall Cortana using PowerShell are as follows:

```
Launch the PowerShell as administrator.
Enter the following command in the PowerShell window and press Enter key.
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.549981C3F5F10 | Remove-AppPackage.
The above PowerShell command uninstalls the Cortana from Windows 10 and Windows 11.
```

To uninstall Microsoft Store, please see:

[Uninstall Store](https://https:/https://blog.techinline.com/2019/03/19/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-windows-store-in-windows-10/)

```
Run Powershell as administrator.
Copy and paste the following command into the Powershell prompt and hit Enter: Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
To reinstall the Windows Store, open Powershell as administrator and run the following command: Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

Now BEWARE:

Uninstalling these things works, but getting them back may require reinstalling Windows.

I had to do this (when it was opportune to do so) after uninstalling Cortana and then having a year's worth of updates.

So my counsel is to leave well enough alone.

Comment: Is there also a way without using all that cryptic comands? I mean some GUI based solution.

Comment: No.  The ONLY way to uninstall these two apps is with Power Shell