# poor performance win10 and howto improve it

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, performance, configure

I have an HP laptop 4GB with intel core M5Y10c 0.80GHz 1.00GHz and windows 10 x64

The performance is really poor and also the UI is slow and unreliable.

I've tried to disable useless characteristics but Windows is still really slow, btw i was not able to remove cortana.

Unfortunately, the laptop RAM can't be upgraded as it has soldered RAM and no slots.

Linux works fine on a different partition but windows is required for some tasks.

Any advise to make it work as expected?
Would a fast NVMe SSD Drive improve the performance?
Are these HW specs "incompatible" for proper usage with a windows above ver 7/8?

additional info:

- HD SATA 3 (6gb/s) avg speed 1017MB/s
  test. min 85MB/s, max 373/MB/s, avg 270 MB/s, access time 0.178ms, burst 139.3 mB/s, CPU usage 32,8%

Comment: “is this hw specs "incompatible" with a windows above ver 7/8?” - Your hardware doesn’t meet the minimum specifications required for any version of Windows

Comment: If your main drive is a Hard Drive and worse 5,400 rpm, then such a machine with 4 GB of memory will be a slug.  Can you upgrade to a fast NVMe SSD Drive?

Comment: Those things were sold with Win10 on them, but they are optimised for battery performance not speed. Usually soldered RAM *and* eMMC SSD, so there's nothing you can do to speed them up.

Comment: The M5Y10c was [released in 2014](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/85234/intel-core-m5y10c-processor-4m-cache-up-to-2-00-ghz/specifications.html) before Windows 10 was released. It also has a TDP of 6W, it is never going to be a particularly fast system.

Comment: You can disable Cortana, [see my reply here](https://superuser.com/questions/1016076/remove-appx-package-for-all-users)  And there will be some other tweaks there to possibly improve the speed just a wee bit.

Comment: I was able to disable Cortana. However I was not able to remove completely, even the icon was still there disturbing me and using space in the bar :(.