# Every app clumped together in Programs folder in Windows 10 Start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

In my glory and wisdom, I accidentally (and programmatically) **moved** the whole `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs` folder to another location on C: when I intended to move one of its subfolders. I said no problem and moved it back to where it was.

Then, lo and behold, I ended up with the following monstrosity:

[image: Start menu mess]

Nothing wrong with anything in the `%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs` subtree, but as in the above screen shot, every app shortcut in the **`%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs`** subtree is all lumped together in the `Programs` folder.

For example, the Access shortcut and AutoHotkey folder should all be on the top level of the Start menu, yet I now have to first open the `Programs` folder to reach them, as if the `Programs` folder were **some new subfolder** added in the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs` folder (like `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Programs`).

There are obviously no options in the Windows Settings that control this, and for the last few days, I looked for registry entries suspected to be controlling this, checked the contents of `desktop.ini` files and kept googling and pulling my hair out, but no dice.

At this point, I suspect it is some **esoteric registry entry** that controls this. The entry must be somewhere in the HKLM subtree, as I have created another account to see the same problem manifesting with the same `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs` folder. I really really hope to have this corrected without reinstalling Windows 10 and re-configuring tons of apps.

Comment: It might just need to be rebuilt. Take a look at this question/answer. https://superuser.com/questions/960406/where-are-all-locations-of-start-menu-folders-in-windows-10

Comment: Can't you programmatically move them back again? It sounds like just removing "programs" from the path would work.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Sorry for the very late reply. No, it doesn't work, either programmatically or manually. I had to reinstall Win 10.

Comment: No problem about the delay. Just sorry to hear about your problem. It's too late now to test my theory, but I suspect that a restore point would have helped.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica "a restore point would have helped." No doubt about it at all. Just that I didn't have a restore point that went far back enough.