# Where I can find the icons from start menu in win 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Where is located the icons from start menu of windows 10, for example if i want to change the default icons from folders of desktop
to the folder icons that are in start menu. [For exaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbyZT.png)

Like if the folder icons of start menu was the icon from folders of desktop.

So i want to know where are located the
[Start menu icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmYS.png)
to can replace the icons like instead of

> %SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll

need to be

> (Where are located icons)

Comment: The Calculator and Alarms are determined by the icon of the application itself (i.e. Microsoft).  However, the icon being a folder instead of the Battle.net icon is either caused by the fact it's a folder or the icon cache is corrupt.  So what exactly is your question about the two default UWP application's icons?  Do you have a folder pinned to your start menu for Battle.net.  You should **edit** your question instead of submitting any commentary answering these basic necessary questions.

Comment: @Ramhound now is more understandable?

Comment: You cannot replace UWP application icons only Desktop Win32 applications

Comment: OK, but if i want to replace a Win32 application icons with UMP application icons, i cant?

Answer (score 0):

Check below:

%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs)

Reference:
[Where are ALL locations of Start Menu folders in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/960406/where-are-all-locations-of-start-menu-folders-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you so much, that will help me in what I need to do and related the icons as the look of the start menu (see the photos). Do you know where they are located?