# Windows 10: Traditional "start" programs menu

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-toolbar

(designed to be a self Q and A, but of course, if you have a better solution other answers are appreciated).

I'd like a traditional (windows 98 era) "Start->All Programs" option in Windows 10. How do I re-create a facsimile of this in windows 10 without replacing my desktop manager entirely?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/946674/can-i-enable-the-windows-7-start-menu-in-windows-10/946675#946675 (Classic Shell and StartIsBack++ do not replace the Windows 10 Start Menu)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on an unused portion of the Windows Taskbar (by default
   at the bottom of your screen).
2. Select `Toolbars`->`New toolbar...`
3. Browse to either `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start
   Menu\Programs` or `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
   (either option appears to combine both the "All Users" program menu
   with the current User's program menu).
4. Click the `Select Folder` button

   Unlock the taskbar if not already unlocked (via the right click menu
   of the taskbar).
5. Drag the new toolbar to the far left of the taskbar (windows, search
   and task view icons still appear to the left of it by default) and
   re-arrange your other toolbars (e.g. Quick Launch and the main
   taskbar).
6. Right-click on an empty portion of the new toolbar
7. Un-check both `Show Text` and `Show title`
8. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` -> `Control Panel` -> `Desktop` ->
   `WindowMetrics` in the registry
9. Add a new String value (Reg_Sz) named MinWidth
10. Set to e.g. -360 (360 twips = 24 pixels)
11. Drag `Programs` toolbar size to minimum
12. Lock the taskbar
13. Log out and back in to windows
14. Reload Regedit.exe
15. Navigate to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams` and export the branch to a file
16. Unlock the taskbar, make the toolbar bigger, re-lock the taskbar
17. Log out and back in
18. Export `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams` again as a new name
19. Use a diff tool (e.g. WinMerge or a github repo) to compare registry values. Mine differed in two spots of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop\TaskbarWinXP`
20. The first difference location is probably where you wish to look at - in my case a hex pair value in the middle of my key changed from 40 to 9c.  This is from 64 pixels to over 120 px.
21. Change that hex pair value to 18 (24 px) or something similar.
22. "Dirty" exit windows without allowing the registry to autosave. Accomplish this by control-alt-delete, select `Task Manager`, go to the details tab, then kill explorer.exe.
23. From `Task Manager` `File->Run New Task` and type `c:\windows\system32\userinit.exe`
24. Log off of windows or reboot to preserve your taskbar settings.
25. Delete or rename  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\MinWidth` or set to default value (`-570` = 38px) (based on [Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons))
26. Log out and back in

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to Stardock, as I've had an [ObjectDesktop](https://www.stardock.com/products/odnt/) *($30)* subscription for years, so I'd recommend Stardock's [Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/) *($5 if purchased separately)*.

- Start10 gives users 2 choices for the classic start menu, the Windows 8 style, with transparency and other GUI affects, or the Windows 7 style.

  - It offers a great deal of customization, including adding custom folders/menus [places] to the right side of the Start Menu.
- Whichever option you chose, ensure you you manually add the start menu folders to the [index](https://superuser.com/a/1033110/529800), as Windows 10 does not have either location added by default.